# How can i pass the data from one JPanel to other...?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` which contains 3 `JPanels`. I want to pass the `JTextField` value of one panel to other. Each panel is shown using `JTabbedPane`. I am getting null when i access the value of other text field.  How can i access?

Comment: Please see **Edit 1** in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You don't show any code, and so it's impossible to know why you're getting "null" values.  Two possible solutions if you want all three JPanels to hold JTextFields with the same content:

- Put the shared JTextField outside of the JPanels held by the JTabbedPane and instead in a JPanel that holds the JTabbedPane, so that the field is always visible no matter what tab is displayed, or
- Use several JTextFields but have them share the same Document or "model".

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class SharedField extends JTabbedPane {
   private static final int TAB_COUNT = 5;
   private static final int MY_WIDTH = 600;
   private static final int MY_HEIGHT = 300;
   PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();

   public SharedField() {
      for (int i = 0; i < TAB_COUNT; i++) {
         JTextField tField = new JTextField(10);
         tField.setDocument(doc);
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.add(tField);
         add("Panel " + i, panel);

         // to demonstrate some of the JTextFields acting like 
         // a label
         if (i % 2 == 1) { // if i is odd
            tField.setEditable(false);
            tField.setBorder(null);
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT);
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SharedField");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SharedField());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**Edit 1**
I see that you've cross-posted this on [java-forums.org/](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/46979-how-can-i-pass-data-one-jpanel-other.html) where you show some of your code:

> pacage Demotool;
>   Class:MainFrame
>   This is the actionPerformed code of first panel
>   both str and scrTxt is (public static)

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String act=e.getActionCommand();

        if(act.equals("ADD"))
        {
            str=scrnTxt.getText();
            System.out.println("Hi :"+str);
            Demotool.DemoTool.jtp.setSelectedIndex(1);   
        }
    }
```

> using the belove code i tried to access the data but I am getting null String:

```
 System.out.println("Hello:"+Demotool.MainFrame.str);
```

Problems:

- Don't use static variables or methods unless you have a good reason to do so. Here you don't.
- You're may be trying to access the MainFrame.str variable before anything has been put into it, making it null, **or** you are creating a new MainFrame object in your second class, one that isn't displayed, and thus one whose str variable is empty or null -- hard to say.

Either way, this design is not good.  You're better off showing us a small demo program that shows your problem with code that compiles and runs, an [sscce](http://sscce.org), so we can play with and modify your code and better be able to show you a decent solution.

One such decent solution is to add a `DocumentListener` to the `JTextField` so that changes to the text held by the `JTextField` are "pushed" into the observers that are listening for changes (your other classes).

For example, using DocumentListeners:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class SharedField2 extends JTabbedPane {
   private static final int LABEL_PANEL_COUNT = 4;
   private static final int MY_WIDTH = 600;
   private static final int MY_HEIGHT = 300;

   public SharedField2() {
      TextFieldPanel tfPanel = new TextFieldPanel();
      LabelPanel[] labelPanels = new LabelPanel[LABEL_PANEL_COUNT];

      add("TextFieldPanel", tfPanel);
      for (int i = 0; i < labelPanels.length; i++) {
         labelPanels[i] = new LabelPanel();
         // add each label panel's listener to the text field
         tfPanel.addDocumentListenerToField(labelPanels[i].getDocumentListener());
         add("Label Panel " + i, labelPanels[i]);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT);
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SharedField2");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SharedField2());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class TextFieldPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField tField = new JTextField(10);

   public TextFieldPanel() {
      add(tField);
   }

   public void addDocumentListenerToField(DocumentListener listener) {
      tField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
   }
}

class LabelPanel extends JPanel {
   private DocumentListener myListener;

   private JLabel label = new JLabel();

   public LabelPanel() {
      add(label);
      myListener = new DocumentListener() {

         @Override
         public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel(e);
         }

         @Override
         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel(e);
         }

         @Override
         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel(e);
         }

         private void updateLabel(DocumentEvent e) {
            try {
               label.setText(e.getDocument().getText(0,
                        e.getDocument().getLength()));
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

      };
   }

   public DocumentListener getDocumentListener() {
      return myListener;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution will be making JTextField global so all panel can access it.

Make sure all your panel can access JTextField that is textField is globally accessible.

Following code demonstrate this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(25);
JLabel labelForPanel2 = new JLabel(),labelForPanel3 = new JLabel();
private void panelDemo() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", panel1);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", panel2);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", panel3);

    panel1.add(textField);
    panel2.add(labelForPanel2);
    panel3.add(labelForPanel3);

    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            labelForPanel2.setText(textField.getText());
            labelForPanel3.setText(textField.getText());
        }
    });

    frame.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: R u trying to say public static textfielName?

Comment: @Sujay: Yes. But static is not necessary.

Comment: :public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String act=e.getActionCommand();

        if(act.equals("ADD"))
        {
            str=scrnTxt.getText();
            System.out.println("Hi :"+str);
            Demotool.DemoTool.jtp.setSelectedIndex(1);   
        }
    }

Comment: Next class cunstructor i wrote this code but it sgiving null:System.out.println("Hello:"+Demotool.MainFrame.str);

Comment: @Sujay: what does this line prints: `System.out.println("Hi :"+str); `

Comment: Hi  :prints the textField value, but Hello :null

Comment: @Sujay: What is `Demotool.MainFrame.str`?

Comment: :Demotool is package, MainFrame is className, str is variable.

Comment: @Sujay: You can not access it like this. Instead try this: `System.out.println("Hello: "+scrnTxt.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly are you going to achieve, but maybe try data binding?

Take a look at [BetterBeansBinding](http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home) library.